# creating a Smartgroup out of post held in an organization

Tags: groups, search, smartgroups, search-results, search-builder

I created an organization type called "Extension centers". Each extension center will have a post called President. I have already uploaded all the extension centers and the president details into CiviCRM. Now I would like to create a smartgroup of all the presidents. how do I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution. Create a new Relationship Type of 'President is/of'. Use that relationship to link your Presidents to the Extension Centres (can be done in bulk via Actions from a Search). Then do an Advanced Search using Relationships. Then save as a Smart Group.